# recursion function on tree data to get path

Tags: php, recursion, tree

I want to write function which receive me path to top element, but I can't figure out how it should work..

My example data:

```
$data = array(
    3546456 => array(
        5345345,
        12312312,
        56456546,
    ),
    12312312 => array(
        34534534,
        5675675,
        8678678,
    ),
    567978 => array(
        234,
        756756,
        8678678,
    ),
);

//I have function to return parent.
$parents = getParents(8678678); // eg. $object_id = 8678678 - return [12312312, 567978] , $object_id = 12312312 - return [3546456]

// and my recursion function I tried.
function getObjectPath($object_id) {
    if ($object_id == null) {
        return [];
    }

    $parents = getObjectParents($object_id); 

    foreach ($parents as $parent) {
        return array($object_id => getObjectPath($parent->nid));
    }
}
```

It doesn't work way I need, on the return in getObjectPath(8678678) I'd like to have return array like that:

```
array(
    3546456 => array(
        12312312 => array(
            8678678
        )
    ),
    567978 => array(
        8678678
    )
);
```

Comment: should the expected output also include `12312312 => array(8678678)` ?

Comment: @user633183 no it shouldn't, if element has parent it build tree up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you almost got it, need to have some other check before returning

```
$data = array(
    3546456 => array(
        5345345,
        12312312,
        56456546,
    ),
    12312312 => array(
        34534534,
        5675675,
        8678678,
    ),
    567978 => array(
        234,
        756756,
        8678678,
    ),
);
//I have function to return parent.
$parents = getObjectPath(8678678, $data); // eg. $object_id = 8678678 - return [12312312, 567978] , $object_id = 12312312 - return [3546456]
echo "<pre>";
print_r($parents);

// and my recursion function I tried.
function getParents($object_id, $data) {
    $return = [];
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        if(in_array($object_id, $value)) {
            $return[] = $key;
        }
    }
    return $return;
}

// and my recursion function I tried.
function getObjectPath($object_id, $data) {
    $return = [];
    $parents = getParents($object_id, $data);
    foreach($parents as $parent) {
        $temp  = getObjectPath($parent, $data);
        if(!empty($temp)) {
            $return[key($temp)][$parent] = $object_id;
        } else {
            $return[$parent] = $object_id;
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: yeah but my getParent is sql query so your solution doesn't work.

Comment: oh i thought you said `getParent` returning this `$object_id = 8678678 - return [12312312, 567978] `